# Gitlab SAML Configuration - 404 on metadata

Tags: gitlab, saml

Question regarding SAML configuration.

I'm currently running Gitlab 9.1 CE edition on CentOs 7.  I have an Apache instance on the front end for a reverse proxy to Gitlab handling http(s)

My gitlab.rb has the following configured

```
external_url 'http://external.apache.server/gitlab/'
gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = ['saml']
gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_sign_in_with_provider'] = 'saml'
gitlab_rails['omniauth_block_auto_created_users'] = false
# gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_link_ldap_user'] = false
gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_link_saml_user'] = true
# gitlab_rails['omniauth_external_providers'] = ['twitter', 'google_oauth2']
# gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
#   {
#     "name" => "google_oauth2",
#     "app_id" => "YOUR APP ID",
#     "app_secret" => "YOUR APP SECRET",
#     "args" => { "access_type" => "offline", "approval_prompt" => "" }
#   }
# ]
```

In order to setup SAML my provider is asking for the information returned from http://external.apache.server/gitlab/users/auth/saml/metadata which returns a 404.

In reading the SAML documentation, it mentions that Gitlab needs to be configured for SSL, not sure if this is why the URL mentioned above is returning a 404.

The problem with enabling SSL is that my external URL is already providing that and if I use it as is `https://external.apache.server` then Gitlab is looking for key/cert for that domain on the box which doesn't seem correct.  I don't want to change the external URL as it should be fronted by Apache.  Bit confused on what the proper configuration should be.

Thanks